# c++ read using operator >>

Tags: c++, overriding, operator-keyword

I have a class

```
class BigNumber{
public:
    int digits[100];

    BigNumber();
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, BigNumber& dt);
};
```

I would like to read a number from the stream using operator >> and put every digit in the digits array.

How can I do this?

Comment: Read the number to the `string` first, and then convert each character to the corresponding number (from `0` to `9`). It's so easy.

Comment: Perhaps you should rethink your design - storing an integer using an `int` for every digit is extremely wasteful.

Comment: I tried but I cannot convert a char to int

Comment: There is **[atoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/)** function to do that.

Comment: `ch - '0'`, converts a decimal digit (in the char variable ch) to an integer.

Comment: @Dylan, you are right, but this is homework :)

Comment: @Haroogan the atoi function does not convert a char to an int, it converts a C string to an int.

Comment: If the homework is very urgent, then `char` can easily become C string too (just to get this crap done at last `:)`). Anyway, actually you can write your own function pretty easily, just remember that [Ascii code](http://www.asciitable.com/) of characters denoting digits begin with `48`. So what you have to do is to check whether the character is between `48` and `57` and to subtract `48` from it.

Answer (score 0):

```
`
istream& operator >> (istream& is, BigNumber& dt)
{
    string s;
    is>>s;
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        dt = 10*dt + s[i];
    }
    return is;
}
`
```

you can add it some try catch blocks for being sure about he enters number or something else but i thought it works well actually i hope it works well and i hope it'll help